# Json, Web API, Binding, Binding Model, AutoMapper

Tags: asp.net, json, rest, binding

I need some advice about this problem. This is my POST method and I should pass the Json object through the body, but it gives me this error..
Like.. I have tried every example that I found [FromUri], [FromBody], can you help me with this?

```
     // POST api/Users

            public void Post([FromUri] UsersBindingModels userBindingModel)
            {
                Users user = new Users();
                var newUser = Mapper.Map<UsersBindingModels>(user);
----------->     newUser = // I think I have to parse it here 
                _repository.Insert(newUser);
                _repository.Save();
            }
```

And my error is:
**Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'BindingModels.UsersBindingModels' to 'Models.Users'**

```
//Model
    public class Users : BaseModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Unique]
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool IsTeacher { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Courses> Courses { get; set; }
    } 


//BindingModel
    public class UsersBindingModels
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public bool isTeacher { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Courses> courses { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save changes in repository.This code maybe helps you:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] UsersBindingModels userBindingModel)
            {
                var newUser =_repository.Insert(userBindingModel);
                return Ok(newUser);
            }
```